# How to display date in words in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display date '07/01/2009' as 'Seventh January Two Thousand Nine'. Here, I'm pulling data using a SELECT query. And I need the result(date) in words as well as 'datetime' format.
Sample Query: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DOB,103) FROM StudDetails 
Current Output: 07/01/2009
Desired Output: 07/01/2009(Seventh January Two Thousand Nine)

Comment: Shnugo , Actually I'm pulling a report by fetching data from tables and in that I need to show date in the following format '07/01/2009 (Seventh January Two Thousand Nine)'.

Comment: Okay! But SO still is not a *do-my-work* area, but a *I-got-stuck-with-this-please-help-me* platform. Please show your own approaches, explain what you tried and what is going wrong, ideally you set up a *stand-alone* sample. Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Shnugo, select 
 convert(varchar(10),DOB,103)DOB  -- 07/01/2009 
from StudentInfo; "I don't know the query to get date in words" .

Comment: Hi just closed this as a duplciate... Finding words for date parts is easy, there are built in functions... Finding an answer to "number to words" took me just some seconds. This is a step you should have done before... The code you provide in your last comment has absolutely nothing to do with your issue... Next time please read the hints about *How to ask* and *Create a MCVE*!

Comment: @Jithin send me mail id i will send code for this

Answer (score 1):

Using built-in method you can convert only month and day of week to string:

```
select DATENAME (month, GETDATE()), DATENAME (weekday, GETDATE()),
```

returns:

```
January, Thursday
```

or you can get help form [here](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/863002/sql-server-date-convert-to-in-word)

Comment: ishan joshi, Actually I'm pulling a report by fetching data from tables and in that I need to show date in the following format  '07/01/2009 (Seventh January Two Thousand Nine)'.